# вывести два максимальных элемента списка без сортировки

Tags: python

Помогите написать функцию чтоб вывести два максимальных элемента списка. однострочным циклом без сортировки
никак не получается

```
a = [2, 2, 3, -15, 2, -7, -12, 2, 3] 
def m(list):
    [x for i in list]
    return x
```

Comment: в представленном случае вы ожидаете вывод ```(3, 3)``` или ```(3, 2)``` ?

Comment: А метод вывода 3 максимальных чисел покажите.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = [2, 2, 3, -15, 2, -7, -12, 2, 3]
>>> a.pop(a.index(max(a))), a.pop(a.index(max(a)))
>>> (3, 3)
```

Comment: Блин, всё время забываю про `pop`, прикольное решение )

Comment: Второй раз pop можно не делать, просто max вернуть: `a.pop(a.index(max(a))), max(a)`

Comment: @insolor Да, все верно.

Answer (score 3):

Кто там говорил, что в одну строчку не получится? Если ищем только разные элементы, то легко:

```
a = [2, 2, 3, -15, 2, -7, -12, 2, 3] 
print(max(a), max(x for x in a if x != max(a)))
```

Вывод:

```
3 2
```

Или ещё вариант с фильтром вместо списочного включения:

```
print(max(a), max(filter(lambda x: x != max(a), a)))
```

P.S. Я потестировал скорость, в общем, лучше прямо вот так как я написал не делать, а вынести `max(a)` в отдельную переменную и в однострочнике использовать уже эту переменную, а не дёргать всё время на сравнениях `max(a)`. Ну и в целом это просто прикольные решения, не самые, конечно, быстрые.

Comment: `Если ищем только разные элементы` это важная оговорка, которую стоит подчеркнуть. Вообще, не стоит экономить на переносах строк в ущерб функционалу. Да и сложность алгоритма с O(n) возрастает до O(n^2)

Comment: @extrn Да ну задачка такая, что тут самое место поизгаляться в прикольных вариантах. )

Comment: @extrn Если пожертвовать строчкой и сохранить `max(a)` в отдельную переменную, то будет по-прежнему `O(n)`, хотя я не уверен, что `Python` сам не закэширует это значение, надо проверять.

Comment: Уверен, что не закеширует. Даже если компилятор мог бы удостовериться в том, что max - чистая функция (даже близко не может, это не Haskell), она таковой не является, потому, что может "портить" итератор, да и сам итератор может не быть чистым

Comment: @extrn Да, вы правы, я проверил. Так что так как я сделал - это только по приколу, на маленьких списках делать )

Comment: +1 Уважаю тех, кто может у̵т̵е̵р̵е̵т̵ь̵ ̵н̵о̵с̵  победить в споре c @insolor

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, нельзя утереть нос в споре тому, кто в споре не участвовал

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [2, 2, 3, -15, 2, -7, -12, 2, 3] 
def two_max(lst):
    first = max(lst)
    second = max(i for i in lst if i != first)
    return first, second

two_max(a)
```

> ```
> (3, 2)
> ```

;)

Comment: Ну вообще-то максимальные элементы - третий и девятый, так что правильный ответ `(3,3)`.

Comment: @Akina спорный момент ;)

Comment: Чего тут спорного? или будете спорить с тем, что третий и девятый - это разные элементы, просто значения у них равны?

Comment: @Akina я имею в виду считать ли одинаковые значения...

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, если вам дадут список чисел на листочке и скажут выписать два самых больших числа из этого списка, вы вторую тройку проигнорируете?

Comment: @insolor Смотря как будет сформулировано задание.

Comment: Вот именно так как я написал: выпишите из списка 2 самых больших числа.

Comment: @insolor Тогда `(3, 3)`